# javascript for all textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want apply my JS on all my Textarea

```
  $_PAGE->addJSOnLoad("
    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
      var nombreCaractere = $(this).val().length;
      var msg = nombreCaractere + ' caractére(s)';

      $('#compteur').text(msg);
      '<span id=compteur>' 0 caractére(s)'</span>';
    });
  ");
```

This code is in constructor of my class textarea I wnat call him 1 times for all textarea

Comment: Not sure how that code would event work with one textarea.

Comment: you are using id `#` instead of class `.`

Answer (score 1):

You should change the jquery selector from `$('#textarea')` to `$('textarea')` so as to target all textarea in the document. 
Also you may want to use `$('.compteur')` in place of `$('#compteur')` so that your can have multiple counters, one for each textarea. Do not forget to update your html correspondingly

Edit: Please use `$(this).find('.compteur')` in place of `$('.compteur')` so that only the counter within the current textarea is affected

Comment: I haven't actually tested it out yet. but i don't see a reason why it shouldn't

Comment: thank you for your answer but now went I write in textarea the counter is up for all textarea ;(

Comment: @kharhys apparently you're right about `this`, however, some distinction between all different counter-elements have to be made

Comment: That is correct @Jakumi. I believe the lack of distinction is what causes the counter to increment on all `textarea`s

Comment: @mokmok I have edited the answer with the correction

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textarea')
```

selects a HTML element with the ID "textarea". So this will be at max one textarea-element. The selector for all textareas would be just

```
$('textarea')
```

Answer (score -2):

javscript event handlers can take a parameter (Event), so

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  var nombreCaractere = $(this).val().length;
  var msg = nombreCaractere + ' caractére(s)';

  // code for display, todo!
}
```

would put the event handler on every textarea (`<textarea>`) on your page. However, the display for the character count is a bit more difficult, unless it's one fixed element that scrolls along.

but let's say, your textareas all have an attribute `data-charcount="[id]"` that has the id of a div or something, that will display the character count.
Then you could replace

```
  // code for display, todo!
```

with

```
  $("#"+this.dataset.charcount).text(msg); // <- assuming this works
```

and your example textarea should look like this:

```
<textarea data-charcount="compteur"></textarea>
<span id="compteur"></span>
```

please note: every id should only appear once!

**edit** replace `event.target` with `this`, and fixed small error with string concat

Comment: it's work but I have counter juste for first textarea :(

Comment: so ... have you added a counter for every textarea? they don't just grow out of thin air.